# Network link conditioner on 100% packet loss - why I am getting internet reachability status wrong?

Tags: ios, reachability

I am checking the status of internet reachability using class "Reachability". But while testing, if I am setting *100% packet loss* in developer settings, still I get reachability status as "ReachableViaWiFi". I am confused what's happening. Shouldn't it be "NotReachable" in that situation ?

Here is my code snippet:

```
Reachability *networkReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
NetworkStatus networkStatus = [networkReachability currentReachabilityStatus];

if(networkStatus == NotReachable){
    NSLog(@"NotReachable");
}
else if(networkStatus == ReachableViaWiFi){
    NSLog(@"ReachableViaWiFi");
}
else if(networkStatus == ReachableViaWWAN){
    NSLog(@"ReachableViaWWAN");
}
```

Is there any other way that give me status as FALSE in this situation?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you found out why?

Comment: Please refer to my answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of packets that you lose doesn't influence reachability. After all, this could be just momentary (you took your phone into a shielded room, or a heavy electrical motor was just turned on). Reachability is about your WiFi, or 3G, or Ethernet on a Mac, being turned on. It's not about the quality of the connection.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
-(BOOL)connected
{
    Reachability *r = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [r currentReachabilityStatus];

    if ((internetStatus != ReachableViaWiFi) && (internetStatus != ReachableViaWWAN))
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: at 100% packet loss with wifi connection on this function will report "YES", so it doesn't solve original OP's problem